# What is the fundamental difference between SomeProtocol.Protocol and SomeProtocol.Type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, metatype

By chance, I observed some differences in behaviour between the types `SomeProtocol.Protocol` and `SomeProtocol.Type` (before this, I thought they are the same thing!):

```
public protocol P {
}

public class C: P {
}

protocol Q: P {}

P.self is P.Protocol // true
P.self is P.Type     // false
Q.self is P.Protocol // false
Q.self is P.Type     // false
C.self is P.Protocol // false
C.self is P.Type     // true

// this seems to be consistent with function invocation expressions, which is expected
func a(_ x: P.Protocol) { }
func b(_ x: P.Type) { }
a(P.self)
b(P.self) // error
a(Q.self) // error
b(Q.self) // error
a(C.self) // error
b(C.self)
```

What surprised me is `P.self is P.Protocol`, [because I know protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), so I expected it to be true...

Anyway, I cannot see what the fundamental difference between `.Protocol` and `.Type` that caused this difference in behaviour. I expect that the two syntaxes probably *mean* something subtly different...

I checked the [Swift guide on meta types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455), which just says:

> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
>   that type followed by `.Type`. The metatype of a protocol type — not
>   the concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime — is the
>   name of that protocol followed by `.Protocol`. For example, the
>   metatype of the class type `SomeClass` is `SomeClass.Type` and the
>   metatype of the protocol `SomeProtocol` is `SomeProtocol.Protocol`.

It doesn't seem to acknowledge the existence of `SomeProtocol.Type`!

What is the difference between `.Protocol` and `.Type`?

(In case it's unclear, I'm looking for an answer along the lines of "`.Protocol` *means this*, where `.Type` *means that*")

Comment: If there are "A" and "B", what is the difference between them... the answer is in question - *"is the name"*.

Comment: @Asperi Well, clearly it's not only the name, because they exhibit different behaviours...

Comment: @Sweeper `P.Type` denotes a type that conforms to `P` and `P.Protocol` denotes a protocol type itself. So, `C.self` is a type of `P` (because it conforms), but `Q.self` is still a protocol - not a type that conforms (aka implements `P`)